# Custom annotation processing in java

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

i know how to create custom annotation , annotation processor and how to configure eclipse ide java compiler for annotation processing, but i would like to know that  ,
in case of hibernate , or TestNg, when we use their jar in our project , we didn't configure java compiler like we do in custom annotation , so how annotation processor for hibernate or testNg gets called? as we need not to set any external jar for annotation processor , how that works internally can any body please explain ? 
Thanks ..

Comment: The question is more about "how it works with Hibernate". I suggest that the annotation processing begins when you initiate the EntityManager (JPA) or the session (pure hibernate) then it parses your persistence.xml, and in it see wich classes to parse in your project.

Comment: can you elaborate please and how the eclipse ide compiler,got idea about annotation processor, if we didnot configure external jar in compiler option -> annotation Processing->factory path option

Comment: I don't know for eclipse.I was talking about the runtime execution. I don't need Eclipse to parse my Hibernate annotation (except for classes import but i still don't see the problem with eclipse)

Comment: They will be using the Java reflection APIs to get the annotations on the classes. Things like `Method.getAnnotation`, `Class.getAnnotations`

Comment: hey i just wanna know if i created a custom annotation , made a jar of its, and if i would like to distribute it to some programmer, the another person ,should use it  as it is, he does not have to make any setting like we do in case for custom annotation, take example  of hibernate as we use jar directly , we don't do any setting in compiler side whether it eclipse or any ide

Comment: can u suggest any links where i can read about internal working of hibernate annotation processor

Comment: @VivekKamble : Did you get any solution for this question?